# Django sql query,'__startswith date and time'

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

here is my Django sql query

```
Mpool.objects.filter(From__startswith=From,To__startswith=To)
```

In the same way, I need to do it for `date` and `time` field in SQL table my date is in this format `2017-02-07` and my time is in `01:00:00` is there a way to do it?

Comment: startswith in date and time??? I think you misunderstood it

Comment: Hi Catherine, may be Iam wrong ,, anyways what iam trying to do is iam going to add date fields in seach options so that when user selects `From date and/or To date` he will get the fetched results from database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mpool.objects.filter(date__gte=start_date, date__lte=end_date)
```

Comment: same, just change `date` to `time`

Comment: Django's range filter provides a shorthand for this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/models/querysets/#range

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your text into date objects then use django's [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#range) filter.

Use python's [strptime()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) function to get the dates from strings.

Something like -

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date_string, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date_string, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

Mpool.objects.filter(your_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Comment: No problem, looks like I misunderstood the question. Glad you got it sorted anyway.